# Reading large .accdb file raise exception "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-access

I debug some legacy ASP.NET application which try to read a huge .accdb file (aprox. about 550 000 rows). Code as follows:

```
OleDbConnection sourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + destinationFile);
        OleDbDataAdapter sourceAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + tableName + "]", sourceConnection);
        DataSet sourceDataSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            sourceConnection.Open();
            sourceAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
            sourceAdapter.Fill(sourceDataSet, tableName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0, ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sourceConnection.Close();
        }
```

At some moment I got exception:

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

```
Server stack trace: 
at     System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at Access2010.IAccessService.LoadFromMDB(String destinationFile, String tableName)
at Access2010.AccessService.LoadFromMDB(String destinationFile, String tableName)
```

Is anybody know what it can be and how to fix it ? 
As I understand best choice to rewrite SQL query to retrieve data by small chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the Upsizing wizard built into access to drop it all into an SQL Express database, and change the connection string.

Side note, don't do this:

```
"select * from [" + tableName + "]"
```

Make it a parameterized query instead.